# What does vegeta call goku black in dragon ball super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

So I just realized the conundrum of Goku Black and Vegetas stubborn namming sense. Since the arc is a while away from being dubbed, I don't want to binge the entire arc again just to find any instance of Vegeta saying Goku Blacks name. So what does he call Goku Black? And does he call him something different after it's revealed who he really is?

Comment: " And does he call him something different after it's revealed who he really is?" . No "what does he call Goku Black?" I dont understand your question. Do you mean why does he call Goku Black? or how Goku Black is called? or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really interesting question. Vegeta has never called his name out in person but whenever he refers to him to the others, he calls him Black.